# Having trouble recursively calling my algorithm

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing a divide and conquer algorithm but I'm having trouble recursively calling it. It says it cannot find the symbol method Multiply and the variables m, e, m

```
public class Multiply {

    private static int randomInt(int size) {
        int maxval = (1 << size) - 1;
        return (int)(Math.random()*maxval);
    }



    public static int[] naive(int size, int x, int y) {
      int[] result = new int[3];

      if (size == 1) {
        result[0] = x*y;
      }

      else {
        int m = size/2;
        int a = x/2;
        int b = x % (int)Math.pow(2,m);
        int c = y / (int)Math.pow(2,m);
        int d = y % (int)Math.pow(2,m);
        int e = Multiply(a,c,m);
        int f = Multiply(b,d,m);
        int g = Multiply(b,c,m);
        int h = Multiply(a,d,m);
      }
        return ((int)Math.pow(2,2*m)*e) + ((int)Math.pow(2,m)*(g+h)) + f; 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Multiply.naive(x,y,z)` instead of `Multiply(x,y,z)`

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to work but I get a new error (/Multiply.java:27: incompatible types
found   : int[]
required: int)

Comment: that problem is in your `return` line. try: `result[0] = ((int)...` then `return result;`